# Play Framework: Sessions, Login/Logout Options

Tags: playframework-2.0, session-cookies, login-control

Hope you can help, seriously getting frustrated with this. I'm using Play 2! and Java. All I want to do is have certain links in my main navigation only present if logged in.

Such as 'Login' if logged out and 'Logout' if logged in etc.

This seems to have been covered a few times but none work for me.

**My Template**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="@routes.UserController.registration">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="@routes.Application.logout()">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My Cookie example**: "e5e9fd6231e0f0296d5f41a2edd05bcc6014a173-email=jeff%40example.com

**What I Want To Do:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if(***user is logged in***){
      <li><a href="@routes.Application.logout()">Logout</a></li>
    } else{
      <li><a href="@routes.UserController.registration">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="@routes.Application.logout()">Login</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Hopefully someone can offer up some advice.

Thanks in advance...

PS. have looked at...
[Toggle Login/Logout based on if user is already logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331142/toggle-login-logout-based-on-if-user-is-already-logged-in) 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/_6HWFJUzWPE

and many other variations but appear useless :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try using your session like this, when the user logs in, add the their email to the current session:

```
Redirect(...).withSession("email"-> "jeff@example.com")
```

You can also set the cookie like this:

```
Redirect(...).withCookies(
   Cookie("email","jeff@example.com",Some(duration),"/",Some(".example.com"),false,false)
)
```

Then when you want to serve the page where you have different behavior depending on whether a user is logged in or not, do this in your controller:

```
val emailOpt = request.cookies.get("email")
```

if you're using cookies, or:

```
val emailOpt = request.session.get("email")
```

if you're using just the session.

`emailOpt` is an `Option` of the email `String`. Pass it along to your template, then use it in your template like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if(emailOpt != None){
      <li><a href="@routes.Application.logout()">Logout</a></li>
    } else{
      <li><a href="@routes.UserController.registration">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="@routes.Application.logout()">Login</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like a Scala implementation? I'm using Java and I'm not managing or modifying any Cookies, I have just used the following tutorial http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide4.

Everything works fine... is there not just some simple snippet like

    @if(session.connected()){
        blah blah blah
    }

Comment: I didn't know you were using Java, as there is no Java tag on your question, so I went with Scala. The Java implmentation should be about the same, except for None you would be using null. I recommend you check the doc about Cookies and Sessions in Java, the solution I gave is still valid with some modifications I believe.